# Difference between two times follow up (Convert to decimal)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I asked a question like this earlier and got a great answer but I made a mistake and wanted the output to be a decimal rather than a time. So here's the question.

I have two textboxes that allow a user to enter a start time and an end time in this format (h:mm). I want it to return the difference in a label. For example, if a user enters 1:35 in the first textbox and 3:30 in the second textbox and press the 'Calculate' button, it will return the decimal 1.92.

Any ideas or resources for this? I only want to calculate decimal difference of the time entered, date and seconds doesn't matter at all. Below is the code for getting an output in the format of (h:mm).

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox1.Text); //"1:35"
TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox2.Text); //"3:30"

label.Text = (ts2 - ts1).ToString();         //"1:55:00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(ts2 - ts1).TotalHours.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want the total number of hours, in that 1.92 hours is 115 minutes (ish).

In that case you want:

```
double hours = (ts2 - ts1).TotalHours;
```

... you can then format that how you wish (e.g. to 2 decimal places).

For example:

```
TimeSpan ts1 = TimeSpan.Parse("1:35");
TimeSpan ts2 = TimeSpan.Parse("3:30");
double hours = (ts2 - ts1).TotalHours;

Console.WriteLine(hours.ToString("f2")); // Prints 1.92
```

Of course I'd personally use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) and parse the strings as `LocalTime` values instead of `TimeSpan` values, given that that's what they're meant to be (times of day), but that's a minor quibble ;)

Comment: Beat by the Skeet yet again. Someday I'll win one.